# cannot find AppservRealm class in NetBeans6.9 with glassfish3 Community Edition

Tags: netbeans, jakarta-ee, glassfish

I am trying to write custom Realm class, but cannot import package which contains it. May be its because of Community version of glassfish which does not contain specific tools for JAAS ? But I cannot find any mention about it in Internet or Oracle site.

I also cannot find ProgrammaticLogin class.

P.S. I use JavaEE1.4 because need use BMP beans, but JAAS is being included in EE since 1.3 as addons and since 1.4 as part.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have GlassFish Server Open Source Edition 3.1 Build 43 installed.  I was able to find com.sun.appserv.security.AppservRealm in the file glassfish3/glassfish/modules/security.jar.

ProgrammaticLogin is in the same jar.

HTH

Comment: I sure that I imported whole module folder before and try 2 version of GF and 3 version of NB. But now I add security.jar alone and it works. Thanks.